# How to send communication to parent component from child component?

Tags: angular5, angular-material-5

I have split up the components only for the reason the base or the ***parent component*** code is growing in size and for code organization. so split the components based on the sections of the ***parent component***.

So the each ***child component*** are the each section of the same ***parent component***. But my question how  to access the ***child component*** objects from ***parent component***? Because most of the examples i see are based on the click event from ***parent component*** to view the ***child component*** (*like dialog*) and the value is passed back to the parent html click event and captures the values using emitter and output parameter.

Whereas in my case there is no such click action to trigger the ***child component***. So how to communicate the values from ***child component*** to ***parent component***?

Comment: How are the values changing in your child component? (e.g. what triggers these changes?)

Comment: I have two sections in child component and each component value has to be emitted independently. And only after the values are entered/changed in the child component, the value has to be emitted to parent component.

Comment: Please check my approach I follow in my code. I am struck with an error. Please help to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In parent component

```js
  onDocumentSelect( documentData: IDocument) {
console.log(documentData);
  }
```

```html
  <app-document [showDocument] = 'displayDocument' (selectDocument)=onDocumentSelect($event)></app-document>
```

In Child component:

```js
  @Output() selectDocument: EventEmitter<e.IDocument>;

  @Input() showDocument: boolean;
```

I am triggering emit in the function where the data for the DocumentSource is computed.

```js
this.selectDocument.emit(this.DocumentSource.data);
```

here this.DocumentSource is the dataTable which has value in Child component, that needs to be accessed in parent component.

Apart from this I have similar data for another field of different type needs to be passed to parent component from child component.

I get the below error while page loads

TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: Here this.DocumentSource.data will have the data of type e.IDocument

Answer (score 0):

In the above code snippet, by changing the type to any solved the issue.

On child component:

```js
@Output() public selectDocument: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

On parent component:

```js
  onDocumentSelect( documentData: any) {
console.log(documentData);
  }
```